# Mapbox GL JS React: Popup Misalignment Issue with Clicked Points

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm working on a React project using Mapbox GL JS and encountering an issue where the popup is not aligning correctly with the clicked points on the map. The popup appears, but it's offset from the intended location (the clicked point). I've tried adjusting the offset prop and other style settings in the Popup component, but the issue persists.

1. Click on Pointer on Map
2. Popup appear on the bottom of the page outside of map
3. How to fix it?

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import Map, { Source, Layer, Popup } from 'react-map-gl';
// ... other imports

const geojson = {
  // geojson data
};

const MapGL = () => {
  const [popupInfo, setPopupInfo] = useState(null);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  const onClick = useCallback((event) => {
    const { features } = event;
    if (features && features.length > 0 && features[0].layer.id === 'point') {
      const feature = features[0];
      setPopupInfo({
        longitude: feature.geometry.coordinates[0],
        latitude: feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
        description: feature.properties.description,
        title: feature.properties.title,
      });
    } else {
      setPopupInfo(null);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Map
      ref={mapRef}
      // ... other map props
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      <Source id='my-data' type='geojson' data={geojson}>
        <Layer id='point' type='circle' paint={styles} />
      </Source>
      {popupInfo && (
        <Popup
          longitude={popupInfo.longitude}
          latitude={popupInfo.latitude}
          closeButton={false}
          closeOnClick={false}
          offset={[0, -30]}
          anchor='bottom'
        >
          <div>
            <strong>{popupInfo.title}</strong>
            <p>{popupInfo.description}</p>
          </div>
        </Popup>
      )}
    </Map>
  );
};

export default MapGL;
```